# How to hide shadow when open SlidingMenu?

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

In my application for set menu i use **SlidingMenu** and for this i write below code.
In my codes **SlidingMenu** it's work and not error.
But in my code when open **SlidingMenu** set black shadow to my `mainLayout`.
I want when open SlidingMenu **not set shadow** to my `mainLayout`.

**My codes:**

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawer_layout, R.drawable.icon_alarm, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        layoutRoot.setTranslationX(-slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth());
        drawer_layout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
        drawer_layout.requestLayout();
    }
};
drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

How can i it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do write one line as following :

```
 drawerLayout.setScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,android.R.color.transparent));
```

It will remove the black shadow while you open navigation drawer. You can do it by programmatically.

Comment: Glad to help you.